# Amazon AWS SES Error - Throttling failure: Maximum SigV2 SMTP sending rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

The error `Throttling failure: Maximum SigV2 SMTP sending rate exceeded.` suddenly started to appear in our .NET application though there were no exceeding any quota (14 mails per second or 50000 per day) in our AWS Sending Statistics.

I can see many similar issues about `Throttling – Maximum sending rate exceeded` on StackOverflow but I'm confused about `SigV2` in my error message.

Searching in [other resources like this one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=960891) gave me the idea that this issue started to happen recently from about October 20, 2020, and there is no exact answer to why this happened. The only solution I can see is to migrate from using SigV2 signing process to [the new method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html).

The question is: Why this happened and can this issue be solved without changes in the application code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a service quota issue. The issue you are facing is due to excessive authentication requests from your side. This issue will not occur if you renew your SMTP credentials in the SES console to use Sigv4 credentials.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Answer (score 1):

As you can see your [daily rate exceeded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-quotas-errors.html)

But you can [open a case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-quotas-request-increase-procedure.html) and [increase your maximum rate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-quotas-request-increase.html)

Comment: rzlvmp, please read the question carefully. This is not about exceeding quotas.

Comment: @elshev Sorry, my bad. Looks like only AWS support can answer about this problem.